# Adding contact to distribution list: The Principal object must have a valid SID IdentityType in order to perform this operation

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to add a `Contact` to a distribution list.

Here is how I am going about it:

```
public void AddContactsToGroup(string groupName, string[] userNames)
{
         using (PrincipalContext context = GetPrincipalContext())
         {
            var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Name, groupName);

            if (group.IsSecurityGroup.HasValue && group.IsSecurityGroup.Value == true)
               throw new ArgumentException("Groups cannot be security groups.");

            foreach (var userName in userNames)
            {
               var query = new ContactPrincipal(context)
                              {
                                 Name = userName
                              };

               var user = Search(query).First();

               group.Members.Add(user);
            }

            group.Save(context);
         }
      }

  private List<T> Search<T>(T query) where T : Principal
  {
     var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
     searcher.QueryFilter = query;
     PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = searcher.FindAll();

     return results.Cast<T>().ToList();
  }
```

Here is the `ContactPrincipal` class (I borrowed this from somewhere):

```
   [DirectoryObjectClass("contact")]
   [DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
   public class ContactPrincipal : AuthenticablePrincipal
   {
      public ContactPrincipal(PrincipalContext context)
         : base(context)
      {
      }

      public static ContactPrincipal FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
      {
         return (ContactPrincipal) Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof (ContactPrincipal), identityValue);
      }

      public static ContactPrincipal FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType,
                                                    string identityValue)
      {
         return
            (ContactPrincipal)
            Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof (ContactPrincipal), identityType, identityValue);
      }

      [DirectoryProperty("mail")]
      public string EmailAddress
      {
         get
         {
            if (ExtensionGet("mail").Length == 1)
            {
               return ExtensionGet("mail")[0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
               return null;
            }
         }
         set { ExtensionSet("mail", value); }
      }

      [DirectoryProperty("givenName")]
      public string GivenName
      {
         get
         {
            if (ExtensionGet("givenName").Length == 1)
            {
               return ExtensionGet("givenName")[0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
               return null;
            }
         }
         set { ExtensionSet("givenName", value); }
      }

      [DirectoryProperty("middleName")]
      public string MiddleName
      {
         get
         {
            if (ExtensionGet("middleName").Length == 1)
            {
               return ExtensionGet("middleName")[0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
               return null;
            }
         }
         set { ExtensionSet("middleName", value); }
      }

      [DirectoryProperty("sn")]
      public string Surname
      {
         get
         {
            if (ExtensionGet("sn").Length == 1)
            {
               return ExtensionGet("sn")[0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
               return null;
            }
         }
         set { ExtensionSet("sn", value); }
      }

      [DirectoryProperty("mobile")]
      public string MobileTelephoneNumber
      {
         get
         {
            if (ExtensionGet("mobile").Length == 1)
            {
               return ExtensionGet("mobile")[0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
               return null;
            }
         }
         set { ExtensionSet("mobile", value); }
      }

      [DirectoryProperty("telephoneNumber")]
      public string VoiceTelephoneNumber
      {
         get
         {
            if (ExtensionGet("telephoneNumber").Length == 1)
            {
               return ExtensionGet("telephoneNumber")[0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
               return null;
            }
         }
         set { ExtensionSet("telephoneNumber", value); }
      }
   }
```

My problem is, when I hit the

```
group.Members.Add(user)
```

line in the `AddContactsToGroup` method, an error is thrown that states

> *The Principal object must have a valid SID IdentityType in order to perform this operation.*

When I interrogate the properties of the `ContactPrincipal`, the `Sid` is, in fact null. This isn't surprising since a `Contact` is an object with no security.

How can I add a `Contact` to a non-security group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use SIDs? Otherwise, what are you using to uniquely identify your users and groups? GUID?

---

1. Are you sure the `ContactPrinciple` search query is returning the correct results?  The section [Finding Ourselves in Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx#S6) might be helpful. Why don't you search for each user by using the `ContactPrincipal`  `FindByIdentity` rather than the search query?
2. Along the same lines, maybe you should add a line that will check if the user principle is equal to `null` before trying to add it to the group.

   if(user != null)
   { 
       group.Members.Add(user);
   }
3. Also, [this thread towards the bottom](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/222efb3c-ec22-4da1-a2a4-de3e23cacc45) seems to describe the same problem you are having. Here's the solution provided in VB.

   > How to add a contact to a group :)? For some reason adding a contact
   >   to a group through the normal methods you would use to add a user or
   >   group to a group causes an error.  To work around this I used the
   >   following code:
   >
   > ```
   > Public Sub AddPrincipalToGroup(ByVal Group As GroupPrincipal, ByVal ChildPrincipal As Principal)
   >     ' use the underlying DirectoryEntry objects to avoid 
   >     ' issues surrounding contacts and other custom types
   >     Dim deGroup As DirectoryEntry = Group.GetUnderlyingObject()
   >
   >     deGroup.Properties("member").Add(ChildPrincipal.DistinguishedName)
   >     deGroup.CommitChanges()
   > End Sub
   > ```

Other possibly helpful links:

- [Adding and removing users from Active Directory groups in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143052/adding-and-removing-users-from-active-directory-groups-in-net)
- [How to get username and SID for user by a domain name in ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477032/how-to-get-username-and-sid-for-user-by-a-domain-name-in-ldap)
- [What Active Directory field do I use to uniquely identify a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911315/what-active-directory-field-do-i-use-to-uniquely-identify-a-user)

Comment: For point #1 - using FindByIdentity while searching for the Name gives me a null ContactPrincipal, where as using the query-by-example gives me a legit contact albeit with no SID. I am not adverse to using SIDs, I'm saying that they are not on the contact principal objects that I am getting back and this is preventing me from saving the contact. Should I be adding one to the contact?

Comment: Not sure why the SIDs are not automatically generated. However, have you tried implementing a `UserPrincipal` rather than a `AuthenticablePrincipal`. Seems more appropriate considering the attributes you are storing. [UserPrincipal Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx) "With UserPrincipal, you have many properties to get and set information about the user, for example, EmployeeId, EmailAddress, GivenName, and VoiceTelephoneNumber." [See more here.](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/directory-services?page=0,5)

Comment: Your code example worked for me. Thank you very much. I am going to switch to UserPrincipal and see how that works for me as well - might clear up some problems I have with group.Members searches in general. Thanks again.

Comment: Hope I still earn the bounty. :]

Comment: Sorry - I thought accepting automatically gave you the bounty. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your value for the group or the contact is not the expected distinguishedName?

There is however no reason that a contact can not be a member of a security group, or that a security enabled user or group object may not be a member of a distribution group.

Maybe go back to the basics first?

This (minimalistic) code works perfectly assuming the user has permissions.  If not, use the proper user name and password with the directoryEntries.

```
public static void AddContactToGroup(string ContactDN, string GroupDN)
{
  try
  {
    using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + GroupDN))
    {
      directoryEntry.RefreshCache();
      DirectoryEntry Contactgroup = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ContactDN);
      directoryEntry.Properties["member"].Add(Contactgroup.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value);
      directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    string msg = e.Message.ToString();
    throw e;
  }
}
```

ContactDN is the contact's distinguishedName.
GroupDN is the group's distinguishedName.

If this works for you, add on what you need. If not. figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your user either has no SID or is trying to use one that is already taken. Have you looked and what the SID is? Also JSuar is right, with AD it is ALWAYS (I can't stress that enough) a good idea to check for null, the AD objects can return null and not throw any errors, a null check never hurt anybody.

Comment: There is no SID on the contact. I don't know if this is ok or not. If it's not, I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961625.aspx might offer some help, I would look at Microsoft's site and see if they have any info on implementing DirectoryObjectClass, you may need to define a group and add the user to the group, like DomainUsers.