# Link domain account to user profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I'm developing web application using ASP.NET MVC and I want to have mixed authentication - Forms and Windows. Each user will have a profile. How can I link domain account to user profile?

The first idea is to use full username including domain information as account identificator. (Property - `User.Identity.Name`)

*Example:* When **"user_1"** enters the application first time, he will get a profile linked to his full account name: **"user_1@mydomain.com"**. If **"user_1"** changes his name to **"user_2"** he will be identificated as a new user and will lose access to his original profile!

How can I unambiguously identify domain account?

Comment: now if you want to give the user the possibility to change his username, then that should not be a key to identify him. there should be a unique username that never changes, and then you can give him the possibility to create a display name, different from his user name that is used as credential for login/logout

Comment: I've found that there is SID for each user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477032/how-to-get-username-and-sid-for-user-by-a-domain-name-in-ldap